# Dynamic require() on node NODE_ENV with webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am building a simple NodeJs Lambda with webpack. There is a dependent node_module using different configuration file based on NODE_ENV

```
let config = require(`./${process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'dev'}_env.js`);
```

I am setting NODE_ENV in package.json

```
     "serve": "set NODE_ENV=qa&webpack --mode development --watch",
    "serve-windows": "$env:NODE_ENV=qa&webpack --mode development --watch"
```

and in webpack configuration

```
mode: process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'default',
```

No matter what I do, its always including dev_env.js ignoring the NODE_ENV I am setting. I spent all night trying to figure out this looking at different posts, is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack --mode development` sets `NODE_ENV` to development. See the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#usage

Another remark, `default` and `qa&webpack` are non-standard values for `NODE_ENV`. Usually, the expected value is either `development`, `test`, or `production`.

If you want to use this approach, you will have to use a different environment variable, for example:

```
let config = require(`./${process.env.APP_ENV ? process.env.APP_ENV : 'dev'}_env.js`);
```

```
"serve": "set APP_ENV=qa&webpack --mode development --watch",
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for quick response. I understand now that --mode is what is passed as NODE_ENV. The solution you provided should solve the problem but the dependent nodemodule can't be changed, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I do not understand. If you cannot change the posted code, you will have to find another way to determine your environment. Is there really no way for you to update the environment variables in your `qa&webpack` environment? The problem you're having is that the webpack's `--mode` flag injects `process.env.NODE_ENV`, so you will have to work with that fact in mind.

Comment: The code which is adding dynamic require() is in a dependent node_module not maintained. I want see if I can avoid making any changes to it. I was exploring to see if I can use any other plugin to resolve it to right environment file like qa_env, before webpack resolves that require using 'mode' value for 'NODE_ENV'. This discussion has certainly helped bring clarity to the problem. Thx again.